# Cannot save txt file in c# after loading it

Tags: c#, text, save, project

I will try to make this brief. I am making a program of my
 own volition, as a utility for a video game (Dark Souls II.) Part of
 what the program does is save character builds to text files and it
 also can load text files and overwrite them with new information. It
 needs to split the txt file into an array that can be modified when it
 loads the file-that way it can save it to another one. There is alot
 of code so I will only post the relevant stuff, but it is giving me
 out of bounds in a specific location since the way it saves the text
 file is a long line I was only able to split with commas.

```
private void btnChar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
            string fullChar = full[0] 
                + full[1]
                + full[2]
                + full[3]
                + full[4]
                + full[5]
                + full[6]
                + full[7]
                + full[8]
                + full[9]
                + full[10]
                + full[11]
                + full[12]
                + full[13]
                + full[14]
                + full[15]
                + full[16]
                +full[17];
            FlexibleMessageBox.Show(fullChar);
        }
 private void saveCharacterToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Documents (.txt)|*.txt";
            saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = ".text";
            saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
            saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
            string fullChar = full[0] + ", "
                + full[1] + ", "
                + full[2] + ", "
                + full[3] + ", "
                + full[4] + ", "
                + full[5] + ", "
                + full[6] + ", "
                + full[7] + ", "
                + full[8] + ", "
                + full[9] + ", "
                + full[10] + ", "
                + full[11] + ", "
                + full[12] + ", "
                + full[13] + ", "
                + full[14] + ", "
                + full[15] + ", "
                + full[16] + ", "
                + full[17] + ", ";
            //Save file dialog for saving characters
            try
            {
                if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {           
                    //Code to write the stream goes here.
                    File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, fullChar);               
                }
            }
           catch (Exception etc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occured: " + etc.Message);
            }
        }

        private void loadCharacterToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Documents (.txt)|*.txt";
            openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
            openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
            string fullChar;
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //Code to write the stream goes here.
                fullChar = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                full = fullChar.Split(',');
            }
        }
```

Comment: _it is giving me out of bounds in a specific location_ where? and care to add how it is declared the array _full_?

Comment: It is, the very first instance of fullChar under btnChar and also under saveChar fullChar string. The full[] is actually public and it should be splitting into it so the program can modify an existing one and then save it again. If you need a better description or want me to send you the program I can. However it is not posted because it is rather large and I didn't think about how I designed some of it when I wrote it so it is messy... XD

Comment: @snipem1438 you should include how the array `full[]` is initialized. I'm guessing that is it not of size 18.

Comment: It is of size 18 or less, it is a bunch of character data that is selected and randomized from the main wmf. It works fine and saves fine, it just doesn't load the way I want it to. full is a bunch of strings that are included by parameters set by the user. The rest of the program works, this was a side thing I wanted to be able to do basically. Again, I can post the whole thing if you want but it is a lot of stuff and it would be very messy.

Comment: If its size is ever less than 18, then the code that you have posted will try to reference indexes in the array that do not exist. i.e. `full[17]` will not exist if the array size is only 17.

Comment: Also the array will never be less then what I initialized it to, I thought of that when I first made the array. :P I just have all the strings by default set to "". So basically, if it isn't filled it is a blank space. ie, this should not be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are unsure about the effective length of your full array (you say 18 elements or less) then you cannot blindly assume that you have all 18 elements.

Instead you could use the [string.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method to build the string that you want to display or write to file

```
private void btnChar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fullChar = string.Join(",", full);
    FlexibleMessageBox.Show(fullChar);
}

private void saveCharacterToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Documents (.txt)|*.txt";
    saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = ".text";
    saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
    saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
    string fullChar = string.Join(", ", full);        
    //Save file dialog for saving characters
    ......
}
```

But the real cause of the errors is in the code that should get the file content back. There, after getting the filename, you need to read it.
The actual code simply tries to split the filename.

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    fullChar = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    full = fullChar.Split(',');
}
```

Comment: Not blindly assuming, that was the first thing I tried and it made no difference. It will still break when loading and attempting to view the txt file to modify it. It breaks in the btnChar. If I join it like that the only difference it makes is that it displays the file path. I will say though that I should have used join for the save just to make it cleaner, so I appreciate that suggestion.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. The array full is declared as _string[] full = new string[18];_?  What is the exact error message received when you string.Join it in the btnChar method?

Comment: Well it was giving me out of bounds still. I believe I fixed that, but now it just shows the file path if I click the btnChar after loading. It should show the fullChar string like it does normally. It creates that string randomly or if it reads the text file. Apologies for the confusion and thank you again for the join suggestion, I used it elsewhere before you mentioned it and didn't even think to use it here even if just to make it cleaner.

Comment: Now I get it. The code in the Open doesn't read the file, but tries to split the filename

Comment: Alright that fixed it, I appreciate it. I have not messed the OFD stuff very much and some things slip my mind because I have not actually had to use them. So I suppose this is obvious or a silly question to have asked but it was helpful and that is what matters. I will file this for the future since everything else I looked for was useful. Thanks much!